# JS - for loop inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm writing a function to count number, first loop get all the values from table row, the console return:

```
apple is 0
banana is 1
orange is 2
watermelon is 3
```

If there's a number (ex:2) passing to the function, inside for loop will rearrange the number, I wish console return:

```
apple is 0
banana is 1
watermelon is 2
```

But console actually return:

```
apple is 0
apple is 1
apple is 2
apple is 3
apple is 4
banana is 0
banana is 1
banana is 2
banana is 3
banana is 4
watermelon is 0
watermelon is 1
watermelon is 2
watermelon is 3
watermelon is 4
```

Don't know how to fix it, here's my code

HTML part:

```
<tr>
<td id="row_00">apple</td>
<td><a href="javascript:del_list(0);"><img src="delete.gif"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="row_01">banana</td>
<td><a href="javascript:del_list(1);"><img src="delete.gif"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="row_02">orange</td>
<td><a href="javascript:del_list(2);"><img src="delete.gif"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="row_03">watermelon</td>
<td><a href="javascript:del_list(3);"><img src="delete.gif"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="row_04"></td>
<td><a href="javascript:del_list(4);"><img src="delete.gif"></a></td>
</tr>
```

JS part:

```
function del_list(number){
    //passing the number between 0 to 4
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        var list = $("#id" + i).val(); //table row from HTML
        console.log(list + " is " +i)

        if(i != number && list != ""){
            for (s = 0; s < 5; s++) {
                console.log(list + " is " +s)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your html code as well. You are using Dom to read data. Also, reframe your question to suit the needs

Comment: It is very unclear what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: it's hard to believe that this could receive up to 5 downvotes. It's just a bit unclear but if reading carefully, one may understand what he actually wants. However I have to admit that sometimes some will give downvotes anyway (don't need to read the question carefully) if s/he sees that the question has already been downvoted, the more the downvotes count is, the more ***tempting*** (really) it is to give more downvote ***anyway***.

Comment: So sorry for my poor English... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a second for loop, use one loop and skip the {number} element:

```
function del_list(number){
    //passing the number between 0 to 4
    for (var i = 0, index = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        if (i != number) {
            var list = $("#id" + i).val(); //table row from HTML
            console.log(list + " is " + index++);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :) I would really appreciate it if you would accept the answer